# How can I default a standard lookup field on a VF Page

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I am using using a custom javascript button which sends a list of records to a visualforce task page. There is a an apex class which mass creates records based on the records sent to it once fields on the page are populated and a user clicks save.

The JS button code is here: 
https://appexchange.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=00P3000000P3foVEAR

```
// Include and initialize the AJAX toolkit library
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/19.0/connection.js")};
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/19.0/apex.js")};
var idList = {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.<Object_Name>)};
var retURL = window.location.toString();
var proceed = true;
if(idList.length <= 0){
 alert('Please select record(s).');
 proceed = false;
}
if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE')) >= 0) {
 if(idList.length > 100){
 alert('Only maximum of 100 records can be selected.');
 proceed = false;
 }
}
if(proceed){
 window.location="/apex/ABSI_Mass_Task_Action?objIds=" + idList + "&retURL=" + retURL;
}
```

I am wondering how I can modify the code of the JS button to default a value in an input field on the VF page. (Owner id = userid)?

I am not sure if i can set default values for the field in the JS button at the end of the url, or if i need to update the VF page / controller.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to SF.SE baxterfly. If you want assistance, make it easy for us by posting your code. Don't ask people to go and download it to look at it for you. Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Without having seen your code, I'd expect you should be able to set OwnerId equal to $UserId.

Answer (score 0):

You can update your controller to save your userID in a variable.

...then put that variable in your javascript in your VF page using {!varName}